# Why is datatable adding row the top of my table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [using jquery datatable plugin, does fnAddAdd() add rows to the top or bottom of a html tabld](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923856/using-jquery-datatable-plugin-does-fnaddadd-add-rows-to-the-top-or-bottom-of)

I am trying to use datatables with my application and seeing the example of dynamically adding row. It works but is strange. It adds rows above my existing rows. How can I fix this?

Infact please look at this demo page:

http://datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html

and then click on "Click to add a new row". You will see 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4 gets added above the row allan, allan, allan, allan.

How do I tell datatables to add that row below allan and not above.

Comment: @Alexis: It is not duplicate. That solution didn't work for me so I again posted. If I pass false as 2nd argument, the row itself is not added.

Answer (score 3):

I am totally surprised at the answer posted at:

[Using jQuery DataTables plugin, does fnAddData() add rows to the top or bottom of an html table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923856/using-jquery-datatable-plugin-does-fnaddadd-add-rows-to-the-top-or-bottom-of)

and have no idea why it is accepted.

@fbfcn's answer is also probably referenced from there itself. I am not sure though!

Infact if you pass `false` as 2nd argument, no row itself would be added!

The correct answer and the only change that was needed was to set the "`bSort`" parameter to false. Set that and you are done!

Answering it for future references.

Answer (score 1):

The add new row function has an optional bool that says if the table is redrawn or not. So what you are seeing in the demo is sorted by column 1, and when a new item is added it the results are resorted. If you pass false the redraw will not happen and behave as you expect but will not be sorted. You can see this is what is happening by sorting column 1 by descending and then adding rows.

```
$(this).fnAddData(data, false);
```

From [API](http://datatables.net/api):

```
Input parameters:   
{array|object}: The data to be added to the table. This can be:
                1D array of data - add a single row with the data provided
                2D array of arrays - add multiple rows in a single call
                object - data object when using mDataProp
                array of objects - multiple data objects when using mDataProp
{bool} [default=true]: redraw the table or not
```

Comment: If I pass false the row itself is not added. This is what I did: $('#purForm').dataTable().fnAddData(['', '', '', '', '', ''], false);